# redux initial state not working

Tags: reactjs, redux

Trying to set up a really basic redux counter app

this works:

```
const initialState = {
  counter: 0
}

const reducer = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD':
      return state + 1
  }
  return state
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  counter: state
})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  add: () => {
    dispatch(addAction())
  }
})

const addAction = (value) => ({
  type: 'ADD',
  value
});

const Main = ({add, counter}) => (
  <div>
    Counter: {counter}
    <button onClick={add}> Add </button>
  </div>
)
```

I get all that, it fires my action and increments it by 1. however, when I change the reducer like so

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD':
      return state.counter + 1
  }
  return state
}
```

it will turn the 0 to a 1 but then every consequent click it returns me `NaN` and I cant debug to work out why. must be missing something small, I know I don't want to mutate the original counter and create a new one but I cant work out how to do this without breaking it. any suggestions?

Comment: Where do you define your store? I'm guessing you're probably using combineReducers to create your main reducer. Each reducer only has access to the part of the state corresponding to its key, not the full state. State is probably 1 in your reducer so state.reducer is undefined and state.reducer + 1 is NaN

Comment: i define my state like so: `const store = createStore(reducer)` for simplicity I am only using one reducer for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial state is an object with one field: `counter`.

```
const initialState = {
  counter: 0
}
```

In this reducer you are returning a number in the ADD case.

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD':
      return state.counter + 1
  }
  return state
}
```

After one ADD dispatch the state is replaced with a simple number (`state = 1`). So when you dispatch another add you will run `return state.counter + 1` on that number. So you will have to rewrite the reducer to handle a whole object.

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD':
      return {
         ...state,
         counter: state.counter + 1
      };
  }
  return state
}
```

You also have to rewrite the view logic slightly.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  counter: state.counter
})
```

Comment: ok makes sense. only problem now is for some reason {counter} isn't coming through to my main component??

Comment: thanks, it's coming through as undefined which is weird as everything seems to be wired up correctly

Comment: basically it all works but doesn't display on the screen for me (i can tell it's working from console.logs). does it display for you on the screen/

Comment: when I log `store.getState()` it's coming through as `reducer: {count: 0}` that right?

Comment: ok thanks for your help, will try to figure it out (the reason it's counter is coz i changed counter to count) so shouldn't affect it. really weird though

Comment: @TheWalrus I've uploaded the test source code [here](https://ufile.io/rm679) in case you want to look at it. It's just npm install and npm start and it's up and running.

Comment: thanks. I notice you pass {this.props.counter} down to Main, whereas I don't BUT I pass counter, add into main `({counter, add})`, using es6 destructuring, the fact it knows what 'add', surely means it should have a concept of counter...

Answer (score -2):

I had the same error before but after importing these two module It worked nice.

`import { StateProvider } from './StateProvider';`

`import reducer, { initialState } from "./reducer";`